# C# generic method for changing a text of a label from an outside thread.

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Alright, so this is (hopefully) a pretty easy fix, but I'm trying to create a generic method for allowing outside access of a labels, now the windows documentation does give an example on this for a single case

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
...some other code ...
private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textLable.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textLable.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

However I want to create something a little more generic, where I can pass something along the lines of a pointer to the object, however text labels in windows forms do not allow this. Ideally for this case I'd like something that does something along these line (this won't work in forms obviously, just for explainational purposes)

```
...code...
private void SetText(string text, Label* lablePointer)
{
    if (this.lablePointer.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        this.lablePointer.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Is there a method for doing this? I've been looking but it doesn't seem to have been answered anywhere.

Comment: why would you use a pointer??

Comment: Because I don't currently know anything better (if there is a better way of doing this), but it's just to get the gist of the problem across. I'm hoping so I can use this for multiple labels so other threads can access them and save me writting a million of these methods for each label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a pointer - you can just do this:

```
private void SetText(string text, Control control)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
        control.Invoke(new Action(() => control.Text = text));
    else
        control.Text = text;
}
```

You can use `Control` instead of `Label` because the `Text` property is inherited from `Control` (`Label` is derived from `Control`). This makes it a little more general purpose.

You don't need a pointer because `Label` (and `Control`) is a reference type, which means a copy of a reference to the `Label` object is pushed onto the stack when `SetText()` is called, which has a similar effect to passing a pointer in C/C++.

(I'm guessing you're a C/C++ programmer who is switching to C#.)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much.
(and I'm a C/Java programmer)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do more than one thing in your invoke, you can invoke an entire function to do everything in one fell swoop:

```
  private void SetText(Label l, string text){
      if(l.InvokeRequired)
      {
          MethodInvoker mI = () => { 
              l.Text = text;
              //representing any other stuff you want to do in a func
              //this is just random left-over stuff from when I used it,
              //it's there to show you can do more than one thing since you are invoking a function
              lbl_Bytes_Total.Text = io.total_KB.ToString("N0");
              lbl_Uncompressed_Bytes.Text = io.mem_Used.ToString("N0");
              pgb_Load_Progress.Value = (int)pct;
          }; 
          BeginInvoke(mI);
      } 
      else
      {
          l.Text = text;
      }
  }
```

Comment: An example of invoking a function in case there is more than one thing that needs to be done at once.